# Smallest RSA Key File Size possible

Tags: c#, rsa, bouncycastle, encryption-asymmetric

I'm trying to get the smallest rsa key pair file size possible to save with extra encryption on a QR-Code. I'd like the size to be as close as possible to the default 2048 bits, but unfortunatly I've only managed to export it with the additional CRT-Data, which is only usefull for faster calculation. To me size is more important than speed.

I'm using BouncyCastle and managed to create an `AsymmetricCipherKeyPair`. The "oversized" Private Key i managed to get by using:

```
AsymmetricKeyParameter rsaPri = res.Private;
PrivateKeyInfo p = PrivateKeyInfoFactory.CreatePrivateKeyInfo(rsaPri);
byte[] piby = p.Attributes.GetEncoded();
```

Where res is equal to the mentioned `AsymmetricCipherKeyPair`

How can I achieve only getting e,N and d,N from Keypair?

And further more, how can I import it again?

I've done multiple hours of research but I'm strugging to wrap my head around it.

Any assistance is apprechiaded :)

Comment: The [`RsaKeyParameters`](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp/blob/master/crypto/src/crypto/parameters/RsaKeyParameters.cs) object in `rsaPri` (you might have to cast it) has the properties `Exponent` and `Modulus`. You can just read these `BigInteger` values. What exactly is the problem you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as expected there is an easy way of doing this: as progman stated, one can easily parse the `AsymmetricKeyParameter` as `RsaKeyParameters` and extract the values I was looking for.